# OpenModelica FMU for Model Exchange - Parallelized?

Tags: parallel-processing, model, openmodelica, fmi

Is the FMU for Model Exchange code (generated by OpenModelica) parallelized?

If I want parallelization, must I run different FMUs for Co-Simulation in parallel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is a bit unclear what you want:

1. Do you want automatic parallelization of the simulation code inside the FMU?

   - we have some support for this using OpenMP and also some experimental support using TBB.
2. Do you want to run the FMUs in parallel on different threads or different processes?

   - we are working on a tool for FMI co-simulation called OMSimulator which will include some parallelization at the master-algorithm level

Comment: I prefer the first option: parallelization of the simulation code inside the FMU. Is parallelization applied to FMUs (Model Exchange) by default? Please could you recommend me any documentation/paper about this topic?